# Report Builder 3.0 Int issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

new to SSRS

I have the following dataset, that I will use later as a parameter

the issue I have please team, is that my count is 1,2,3 ect

I have the following

*Select distinct cast(Count as Int) as Count, 
                  Cast(Count as Int) as Name 
from Table
**UNION
select '0', 'Count Number Instance'***

the issue is the line in bold. The 0 will be become my default value in the parameter for all, but I am getting an int conversion issue.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UNION` is between different datatypes, `INT` before the UNION and `VARCHAR` after it.

```
Select distinct cast(Count as Int) as Count --this is INT
    ,Cast(Count as Int) as Name -- this is also INT
from Table 
UNION
select '0' --This is VARCHAR(x)
    , 'Count Number Instance' --this is also VARCHAR(x)
```

This may work for you

```
Select distinct cast(Count as Int) as Count
    ,Cast(Count as VARCHAR(22)) as Name
from Table 
UNION
select CAST('0' AS INT) 
    , 'Count Number Instance'
```

What is the datatype of the `Count` column in `Table`

Include in the question your expected output and I will update this answer accordingly

Comment: awesome, made sense, used UNION
select '0', 
     '0', thanks so much team x